# Is personhood different from personal identity?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind, mind-body

I'm confused as to what the difference between these two terms are. Suppose that I am a cognitivist about personhood. Does this imply that higher order cognitive functions underwrite personal identity over time?

I'd be grateful if you could help me with this.

Comment: does [this](https://philarchive.org/rec/OHLPIW) help at all?

Comment: You are the best @prof_post